# Rotate photo file and keep the quality on Android

Tags: android

I use below code to rotate photo file:

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(sourcePath);
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postRotate(90);
bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), matrix, true);
FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(destPath);
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut);
fOut.flush();
fOut.close();
```

It can rotate file success.
But it will make the file get low-quality.
If rotate more and more times, it will become unclear.
I want to keep the quality, how can I do it?

Comment: maybe inPreferQualityOverSpeed will solve it

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.java

Comment: hey just try imageview.setRotation(rotation angle); if your purpose is just the rotation.

Comment: I want to rotate original file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If rotate more and more times, it will become unclear.

This is a compression artifact referred to as [generation loss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_loss). It's the result of compressing a `JPEG` repeatedly. An easyway to stop it is to use a lossless compression method like `PNG`. For instance:

```
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, fOut);
```

You might also be interested in reading: [JPEG - Compression ratio and artifacts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Compression_ratio_and_artifacts)